# Difficulty understanding the Golden Seven Restful Actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

I was looking at the Golden 7 Restful Actions viz.

Index
New
Delete
Update
Create
Edit
Show

Now, I'm totally confused and not really sure if all of these are exclusive? For instance,
what is the difference between Index and Show, New and Create or Edit and Update? Are they essentially the same? Does that mean, we have just 4 golden actions and not 7?

Comment: A link perhaps? I tried to search for it, but just got a bunch of bible quotes...

Comment: Hahahaha. Hilarious. I think I read about them on a blog or article, I don't remember. It is basically the 7 actions that the Rails guys prescribe. http://www.softiesonrails.com/2008/1/29/rails-rest-101-meets-rails-2-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the [Simply Restful Routing](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SimplyRestfulRouting&referringTitle=Documentation&ProjectName=mvccontrib) for an example of the different restful actions and verbs.

Comment: That was a pretty good resource Darin. I think I'm slowly getting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are confused is because it is a terribly bad way of trying to implement REST.
To use the term RESTful action to describe anything other than GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, etc when using HTTP is just nasty.

Even some of the Rails guys are realizing that the seven actions were a [bad idea](http://blog.pluralsight.com/rethinking-rails-3-routes).

Comment: I recommended this answer though I slightly disagree with it because it offered a new idea & good resource for a new topic. Thanks Darrel.

Comment: Based on the golden seven, I started to organize my controllers and actions keeping in mind all my resources. Oh my, I feel so challenged right now. It just feels that I'm trying to squeeze this square peg into this hole just for the heck of it :D I'm worried about ending up with this big fat controller that tries to serve these infinite number of actions just coz I was made to think in terms of 'resources'. Sigh...

Comment: @darrel-miller Your pluralsight link is broken. Can you explain why they're "terribly bad" and "nasty"?

Comment: @DuncanMalashock  I fixed the link.  One of the core principles of REST is the notion of the uniform interface.  The idea is that a standard set of methods are used so that everyone knows what they mean.  HTTP defines a set of standard methods.  For a web framework to invent it's own set of "standard" methods that mostly duplicate those of HTTP is pointless and confusing.